# Handling a value of zero in a date datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm reporting out of a database that is using **decimal(17,6)** as the datatype for a date field. For example, the current date/time in this field would be `20210820.171900`. Unusual, but whatever. I need to convert the original date field from decimal(17,6) to datetime. This is what I have:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(varchar,convert(int, lastmoddatetime)), 0)
from Table1
```

The above statement works correctly as long as none of the records have a value of zero in this column. Unfortunately, the column value defaults to zero (`0.000000`) if no date has been calculated for it. Whenever a column has a zero value, I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date from character string.

How can I overcome this issue? Ultimately, I'm needing to apply a **dateadd** function to the *lastmoddatetime* field.

Note: Before you suggest changing the column definition, this database originated in the 1990's and I'm not allowed to make any changes to the database structure.

Comment: ***Preemptive Note:*** Save your comments about how stupid the field was set up and that it needed to be created properly. I agree with them all. However, this clunky database originated in the 1990's and I'm not allowed to make any changes to the database structure.

Comment: The desired result would be for those records where the date value is zero, it would be converted to an actual date (or remain as zero, unlikely) that could then be otherwise filtered out of the resultset.

Comment: We have no idea what "date field (decimal datatype)" means. We can't see your data to deduce whatever scheme it is using

Comment: I've edited the original question, so hopefully I am being more clear. The bottom line of my question is how to deal with a zero value when converting to a date datatype.

Comment: @RandyDavis I think we need to know what it means to have 0 in that column. You mentioned "if no date has been calculated" but it's not clear what that actually means. Would you want nulls in those cases?

Comment: Just use a `case` to not attempt to convert 0.

Comment: And what value of date time do you want when zero is currently recorded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use `NULLIF` to null out those values**

```
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(15), convert(int, NULLIF(lastmoddatetime, 0.0))), 0)
```

Comment: Good old KISS!!

Answer (score 1):

Either use `TRY_CONVERT` or `CASE` - depending how you want to handle the zero case.

```
SELECT
    -- If desiring null for 0 and SQL Server 2012+
    TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(int, lastmoddatetime)), 0)
    , CASE WHEN lastmoddatetime <> 0
    -- If desiring some other valid date or < SQL Server 2012
    THEN CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(int, lastmoddatetime)), 0)
    ELSE NULL /* Whatever valid datetime value you want */ END
FROM (
  VALUES (20210820.171900), (0.0)
) x (lastmoddatetime);
```

I note that this ignores the time component - so am converting to a `date` not `datetime` above. If you need to handle the time component you need to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option.

You can thin it out a bit by using `left()` and `try_convert()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (lastmoddatetime numeric(17,6))
Insert into @YourTable values
 (20210820.171900)
,(0.0)


Select AsDate     = try_convert(date,left(lastmoddatetime,8))
      ,AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime,left(lastmoddatetime,8))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
AsDate        AsDateTime
2021-08-20    2021-08-20 00:00:00.000
NULL          NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

use

`convert(datetime,convert(int,lastmoddatetime),0)`

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way to convert it to DATETIME. However, when there are some records that have 0.000000 in this field, it will error out. How would I handle this?

Comment: No I tested it works well with records up to 0.000000 no need to convert varchar

Comment: Yes, it allows me to get past the error when the date field is a zero, but when the date field value is 20210823, it now errors out due to a date range error. In your formula, a value of 1 = 1day. 20 million days in the future is out of range. However, you caused me to stumble upon the actual answer here, so yours was most helpful. Thanks.